# Help extending class used in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, class, extend

First, a proviso - I'm a designer not a dev, so please be gentle ;)

I'm trying to tweak a Wordpress plugin by extending a class. In the class in a bit of conditional if/elseif-ing the code calls one of two functions. Instead of these functions I've want to call two new ones (effectively the same functions as the old ones but again, slightly tweaked).

I've done this successfully before by doing this:

```
class MY_CLASS extends MY_NEW_CLASS { ...
```

Then I change the code in the class and away we go. However, in this case it doesn't appear to be working?

Below I've pasted the class code that I've put into my functions.php file:

```
class QA_AJAX_new extends QA_AJAX {

function init() {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_qa_vote', array( __CLASS__, 'vote' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_qa_accept', array( __CLASS__, 'accept' ) );
}

function vote() {
    global $_qa_votes;

    $_qa_votes->handle_voting();

    $id = $_POST['post_id'];
    $post_type = get_post_type( $id );

    if ( 'question' == $post_type )
        the_question_voting_new( $id );
    elseif ( 'answer' == $post_type )
        the_answer_voting_new( $id );
    else
        die( -1 );

    die;
}

function accept() {
    global $_qa_votes;

    $_qa_votes->handle_accepting();

    $id = $_POST['answer_id'];

    the_answer_accepted( $id );

    die;
}
}

QA_AJAX_new::init();
```

About half way down you can see the two new functions I want the class to use, `the_question_voting_new` and `the_answer_voting_new`. I've also changed the code at the end that now says `QA_AJAX_new::init();` - I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do that, but I've tried it both ways and neither makes a difference.

I'm clearly doing something wrong (or trying to do something that's not possible), something a dev would spot instantly, but my poor designer brain doesn't know enough about php to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: define "Not working". Do you get errors, it does something you don't expect or does nothing at all?

Comment: No, no errors. What appears to be happening is that the 'new' class, QA_AJAX_new, doesn't appear to be extending (overriding?) the old class QA_AJAX because the old functions 'the_question_voting' and 'the_answer_voting' are still being used - these functions output some html, which I've changed in my new versions of them, but it's still showing the old html. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that `Init` isn't static so you can't call it using `QA_AJAX_new::init();`. In the script that the form posts to try :

```
$qa_ajax = new QA_AJAX_new();
$qa_ajax->init();
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm showing my ignorance here but where do I put that code? I've tried it just after my code above, so it looks like this: //QA_AJAX_new::init(); $qa_ajax = new QA_AJAX_new(); $qa_ajax->init();. However, that doesn't appear to have any effect - the old class and functions are still being used...

Comment: If you are extending the class functions with the same name will be replaced. It seems like something else is the problem. Does the form post to functions.php ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but functions.php is loaded for every page on a Wordpress site... The site is basically a Q&A site like Stackoverflow. The class above controls the voting buttons on questions/answers. There are two buttons, up and down. Here's the code that sets them up: `foreach ( $buttons as $type => $text ) {
  $buttons[ $type ] = $GLOBALS['_qa_votes']->get_link( $question_id, $type, $current, $text );
 }`. Not sure if that helps though?

Comment: It seems like despite creating a new class the old one is still being called. Try seeing where the link that has been created points to and have a look in the relevant file

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig a little deeper. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [Object Inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php#language.oop5.inheritance.examples.ex1), which seems to be the problem.
Here's a couple of other things you might try...

- In **wp-config.php**, set **WP_DEBUG** to true: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
- Make sure the PHP `display_errors` directive is set to **1**, which you should be able to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your **wp_config.php** file.

This will help see any errors that may be being triggered and suppressed.

One of the most common things I've found as well as other WP developers is that so many plugin/theme authors will not set WP_DEBUG to **true** while writing their code and many times you'll find your error in the messages.

Comment: Thanks Amereservant. I'll be back on this project in a couple of days so I'll look into Object Inheritance and debugging as you've suggested.

Comment: Well I've read up a bit on object inheritance and what I picked up was that you have to make sure the class doing the extending is loaded after the original - makes sense obviously. So I looked into the order in which Wordpress loads files and after a lot of experimenting found a way of doing this for my case (my theme is a child theme which makes things much more complicated). However, no matter what I do, my extended class doesn't do anything to the original class. Thanks for your help everyone, but I think I'm going to have to call it a day on this problem, it's just too technical for me...

Comment: Well it's not necessarily when the files are loaded, but when the class is instantiated, ( new Foo();).  Here's an example of this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kec3fe

So what's probably happening is that you're instantiating your class  before the class it is extending has been loaded, so try loading all of your files first, such as through includes, THEN create the class instance.